# Length limit within a range in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still new to VBA and trying to create VBA code in which users are limited to certain character lengths in each specified column. If the character length is greater, then an error message will display. The code starts at Column B Row 10 and depending on the number of rows the user enters data. I'm not sure what's wrong since I've been trying to debug for awhile now with no luck. Below is my code I hope someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```
Sub LenValid()
Dim sht     As Worksheet
Dim wrk     As Workbook
Dim lrow    As Long
Dim rng1    As Range
Dim rng2    As Range
Dim i       As Integer
Dim finprod As Variant
Dim subprod As Variant

Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook
Set sht = wrk.Worksheets(1)

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets

    lrow = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = sht.Range("B10:B" & lrow) 'CUSTOMER ACCT
    Set rng2 = sht.Range("C10:C" & lrow) 'CUSTOMER NAME
    i = 1
    For i = 10 To lrow

        If Len(rng1.Range("A" & i).Value) > 15 Then
            MsgBox "Customer Acct limited to 15 characters." & vbNewLine & "Please review and correct.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Len(rng2.Range("B" & i).Value) > 10 Then
            MsgBox "Customer Name limited to 10 characters." & vbNewLine & "Please review and correct.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next i    
Next sht

'Error Handler
NothingFound:
MsgBox "Character length in required fields are valid.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Error message? Your code ends as soon as you find  a cell more than 10 in length.

Comment: Also, `rng1.Range("A" & i)` is a relative reference and probably not what you intend.

Comment: The code is not picking up the invalid length when I tested it. For example, the first "IF" statement is to detect character lengths of greater than "15" in Column "B" with a message box indicating the invalid length so the user can edit the data accordingly. However, the code just continued to loop through the next column without a message popup even when the data is greater than the specified criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The code will still exit as soon as long text is found, but at least the message box should appear.

```
Sub LenValid()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim wrk As Workbook
Dim lrow As Long
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim finprod As Variant
Dim subprod As Variant

Set wrk = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sht In wrk.Worksheets
    lrow = sht.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = sht.Range("B10:B" & lrow) 'CUSTOMER ACCT
    Set rng2 = sht.Range("C10:C" & lrow) 'CUSTOMER NAME
    For i = 1 To rng1.Count
        If Len(rng1.Cells(i).Value) > 15 Then
            MsgBox "Customer Acct limited to 15 characters." & vbNewLine & "Please review and correct.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Len(rng2.Cells(i).Value) > 10 Then
            MsgBox "Customer Name limited to 10 characters." & vbNewLine & "Please review and correct.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
Next sht

'Error Handler
NothingFound:
MsgBox "Character length in required fields are valid.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

---

Your problem is probably this:

`Set rng1 = sht.Range("B10:B" & lrow)
If Len(rng1.Range("A" & i).Value) > 15 Then`

If `i=10` this is checking the 10th cell in rng1 as it is relative, i.e. it starts in B20.

Comment: That worked!  I can see the problem now.  Thank you very much for explaining it to me and helping me debug.  Hope you have a great day!!